# XSL Split a value by comma

Tags: xml, xslt

I was wondering how to resolve the error in the XSL code below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Street[1]">
        <xsl:variable name="street" select="substring-before(.,',')"/>
        <Street>
            <xsl:value-of select="$street"/>
        </Street>
        <Street>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(.,',')"/>
        </Street>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Street[position() > 1]">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using the XML below and processing with the XSL code above, the result is coming incorrectly; the result should be in the first tag Street keeping the value before the first comma and in the second tag street the value after the last comma.

Source XML:

```
<Delivery>
         <DeliverTo>john Letter</DeliverTo>
         <Street>Block 1, lorem ipsum, test 123, Last part of the address</Street>
         <Street>Brooklyn</Street>
         <PostalCode>6011</PostalCode>
</Delivery>
```

Current Result:

```
<Delivery>
   <DeliverTo>john Letter</DeliverTo>
   <Street>Block 1</Street>
   <Street> lorem ipsum, test 123, Last part of the address</Street>
   Brooklyn
   <PostalCode>6011</PostalCode>
</Delivery>
```

**Desired result:**

```
<Delivery>
         <DeliverTo>john Letter</DeliverTo>
         <Street>Block 1</Street>
         <Street>Last part of the address</Street>
         <PostalCode>6011</PostalCode>
</Delivery>
```

Comment: Plesse always tags XSLT questions with the version of XSLT you want to use.

Answer (score -1):

I fix it with the below code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Street[1]">
        <xsl:variable name="streetList" select="substring-before(.,',')"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(.,',')">
            <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                <Street>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </Street>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
                <Street>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </Street>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Street[position() > 1]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your stylesheet says `version="1.0"` but the `tokenize()` function requires XSLT 2.0 or higher. If you can use XSLT 2.0 then you can do simply `$tokens[1]` and `$tokens{last()]`without needing `xsl:for-each` or `xsl:for-if`.